# Selenium : How to get locators of elements inside canvas tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas, selenium-ide

I have a Web application which implements Canvas tags . Inside one canvas section there are multiple buttons and other elements. I want to click on the button inside that canvas tag using Selenium WebDriver, But unable to find locators(id,xpath etc) using inspect element, selenium IDE or Firepath etc. Even I am unable to see any other tags inside canvas tag.

Is there any way to get the locators of the elements inside canvas tag or any way to interact with these elements using Selenium WebDriver?

canvas tag:

```
<canvas style="padding: 0px; 
               margin: 0px; border: 0px none; 
               background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; 
               position: absolute; 
               top: 0px; left: 0px; 
               width: 360px; 
               height: 360px;" 
               width="360" height="360"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using parent tag in your xpath? Since inside one canvas section there are multiple buttons, you can try `/parent::*[canvas attributehere]/parent::*[another-canvas attribute here]` .. and so on until you get the specific element

Comment: I can not see the attributes , even tags of the elements inside the canvas.

Comment: This does not look like HTML code which you have attached. It looks like CSS. HTML code with canvas tag would look something like this..<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle='#FF0000';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,80,100);
</script>

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be using x and y co-ordinates.

```
driver.switchTo().window(frame);
WebElement canvas= driver.findElement(By.id("canvas"));
Actions action2 = new Actions(driver);
action2.moveToElement(canvas, canvas.getLocation().getX()+ELEMENTS_DISTANCE_FROM_CANVAS_X, canvas.getLocation().getY()+ELEMENTS_DISTANCE_FROM_CANVAS_Y).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this Java tutorial](https://applitools.com/event/canvas-selenium-java/) could be helpful for someone this is the essential code [from it](https://github.com/applitools/automation-cookbook/blob/main/selenium-java/canvas/CanvasTests.java):

```
var canvas_dimensions = canvas.getSize();
int canvas_center_x = canvas_dimensions.getWidth() / 2;
int canvas_center_y = canvas_dimensions.getHeight() / 2;
int button_x = (canvas_center_x / 3) * 2;
int button_y = (canvas_center_y / 3) * 2;

// Click button on the canvas
new Actions(driver)
  .moveToElement(canvas, button_x, button_y)
  .click()
  .perform();
```